# Why are there 4 cables coming into 2 switches, and then a jumper installed?

Tags: bathroom, switch

I am trying to install toggle style light switches instead of the rocker style that is here. It's for my bathroom,  one light and the fan. The fan doesn't work right now and there are too many connections. 2 coming from the bottom of the wall, from the source I think. Then 2 coming down from the ceiling,  which would be the fan and light. But there was a jumper between the rockers, and when I took that wire out the all the lights in the bathroom went out. Now I have one bottom and top wired together on each switch, and even though the switch is off the light is off. AND when I flip either switch the breaker trips. I'm so confused!

The jumper runs into the first and third hole in the top, then connects to the black and white wires on each switch.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NPC1.jpg)

[![second switch][3]][3]

[![original rocker switch][4]][4]

[image: jumper wire]
[image: inside of box]

Comment: Please post the pictures you should have taken of how it was wired before. If you didn't take pictures of how it's wired now, showing all the cables and wires in the boxes and their connections ot the switches and fan/light. How many breakers must be turned off to completely remove power o the switchbox?

Comment: I didn't take before pictures, but here is how I've got it wired now. Only one breaker has to be turned off. I didnt change any wiring at the light or fan, but I'll also take pictures of the lights and situation as best I can.

Comment: @Ecnerwal How do I add pictures?

Comment: [Edit] your post and use the "sun and mountains" icon above the edit box. Leave the code it inserts alone, other than carefully editing the description text without losing the punctuation or spaces between lines.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Added pictures

Comment: Could you try taking pictures that actually show how you've interconnected the switches? Remember, we are not there and can't move things around or use x-ray vision on the pictures to see things that are not shown. It's highly likely that NO white wires should be connected to the switches at all, and that's why the breaker trips when you flip the switches. Next time, start by taking clear before pictures...before you change the wiring.

Comment: Please don't put more than one wire under a screw. After disconnecting, identify wires with meter and cap the black 'power in'. Cut the power. These are single pole switches, so all white wires will tie together. Two of the blacks will be switch legs, the other black will be power out (one feeder, downstream devices). Pigtail from the power in/out wires to feed the switches (one tail per switch - 4 wires in wing nut), and switch legs to other screws of switches.

Comment: The ground wires are cut off in two of these cables - that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

IF (and it may not be, so you should check with all wires and switches disconnected) the power supply is from below and the fan and light are from above (more likely one lower cable is power supply and one goes on to an outlet that's not switched...) NO white wires should be connected to ANY switch terminals.

If you have some means of testing for voltage, use it (carefully), and identify which wire actually has power with nothing connected. Most likely only one wire will.

That one wire would be connected to one side of both switches, (that's the jumper wire you found originally) and (if it's a black from a bottom cable) probably to the other black wire from the other lower cable to feed an unswitched outlet. Note that is **an educated guess,** not a guarantee. Could be that **the hot wire is white**, in which case, don't read on in this answer - stop and ask for further guidance and we'll talk about old fashioned switch loops.

All 4 white wires would, in that case, be joined to each other and not to the switch. Is that how they were before you started here?

All grounds should be joined to the box if metallic (looks like it's not) to each other so all 4 are joined together, and to the switches via the ground screws since the box is not metallic

The black wires from the upper cables that presumably go to the fan and light would be connected to the other terminal (the one the always hot wire is NOT connected to) of their respective switches.

And suddenly there are not "too many wires" after all.

Comment: thanks,  I think that's got it!